# Kotlin get errors after updating compileSdkVersion to 27

Tags: android, kotlin, android-support-library

I am getting many errors in my fragments after updating `compileSdkVersion` to `27` and updating support libraries to `27.0.2`.

It is possible to fix it without override methods and refactor manually all my fragments?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support libraries now contain correct nullability information for the Android API methods. The nullability of parameters and return values in your code does not match that of the API methods, so you need to fix your code in order to get rid of the errors.